# Plotting categorical variable in logistic regression random effect GLMM

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression, glm, random-effects

first a bit of background to my question:

I have been working with a fairly large data set of animals escaping from holding enclosures (2000+ observations across 6 sites, with ~20 categorical/continuous variables) and have run a logistic regression GLMM with site as the random effect.

Response: Probability of escape (1/0)

Using model averaging I have narrowed things down to two variables (one categorical/one continuous) being important both separately and as an interaction between the two.

Categorical predictor: Quality of enclosure (3 level factor = 1, 2, 3)
Continuous predictor: Number of previous escapes

I am struggling to get an informative plot for the categorical variable and would like some help, please. I would like to show that as the quality of enclosure changes, the probability of escape changes with some kind of trend line if possible.

I have tried the following code for the continuous variable, which gives me what I’m after:

```
ggplot(Breakouts.Scaled, aes(x=Number_of_Previous_Breakouts,y=Breakout)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method=glm, colour="black")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkkCJ.jpg)

However, for the categorical variable I get a fairly uninformative output:

```
ggplot(Breakouts.Scaled, aes(x=Fence_Integrity,y=Breakout)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method=glm, colour="black")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5tsA.jpg)

If anyone knows how to get a plot with a trend line or equivalent for the categorical variable and possibly a plot of an interaction between the continuous and categorical it would be greatly appreciated.

NB. This is my first post on this site (although I have searched for an answer to this before posting) and I am new to R and statistical modelling, so if anything requires further explanation please let me know.

Thank you.